# typedefed struct in an header file is not identifiable in other header files that includes that file

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header-files, typedef

I have a `typedef`ed struct in an header file

**data_stracture.h:**

```c
#if !defined(__DATA__STRUCTURE__HEADER__)
#define __DATA__STRUCTURE__HEADER__
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "tokenizer.h"
/*arraylist implemtation*/
#define INIT_SIZE 4
#define GROWING_FACTOR 2
typedef struct
{
    char** enumerable_items;
    int size;
    int first_free_index;
}list; 
list init_list(void);
bool add_to_end(list collection, char* added_item);
char* get_item_at_index(list access_list, int access_index);
void free_list(list memory_to_free);
list remove_item(list, char *);
/*more....*/
#endif
```

In a second file, in which I have included `file_1.h`, I have declared a method that one of it's parameters is from type `list` struct.

**tokenizer.h:**

```c
#if !defined(__TOKENIZER__HEADER__)
#define __TOKENIZER__HEADER__
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "data_structure.h"
#define WORD_SIZE 24
typedef enum {none, asm_command, ignore, instruction}asm_line_type;

typedef struct
{
    char *label;
    char *op_name;
    struct list operands;
    bool is_instruction;
    unsigned int adress : WORD_SIZE;
    int line_number;
}asm_line_data;
#define NOT_FOUND {NULL, none, -1, false, -1}

bool match(char* command, char* match_template);
struct asm_command_syntax get_instruction_operand_amount(char *command, struct asm_command_syntax match_template);
asm_line_data *get_data(struct asm_command_syntax* command_syntax, struct list commands);
asm_line_data *tokenize(struct list string_commands, long *);
void validate_commas(struct list);
int get_word_amount(char* spaces_text);
struct asm_command_syntax classify(char* command);
#endif
```

Both header files have include guards.

When I am compiling the program with `gcc` (`ansi C`), I get the following compiler error:

```
file_2.h:22:25: error: unknown type name ‘list’
   22 | void foo(list);
```

I have used `list` in `tokenizer.h` many times, and the error is the same.

When I have tried to move the `typedef`ed struct to `tokenizer.h`, and then included `tokenizer.h` in `data_stracture.h`, it worked fine in `tokenizer.h`, but than I got the same error at `data_stracture.h`, whenever I have used `list` there.

Trying to add the struct keyword doesn't work either, generating errors such as:

```
tokenizer.h:12:17: error: field ‘operands’ has incomplete type
   12 |     struct list operands;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
```

How can I prevent such error?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217452/discussion-on-question-by-avivgood2-typedefed-struct-in-an-header-file-is-not-id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem with your code as [@StoryTeller-Unslander Monica stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771548/typedefed-struct-in-an-header-file-is-not-identifiable-in-other-header-files-tha/62772651#comment111005916_62771548) is the circular inclusion.

As far as I can tell you only need the `struct list` declaration in the `tokenizer.h` file.

What you can do is to create a separate header file, let's say `structure.h`,declare the struct there and include it in both `data_structure.h` and `tokenizer.h`.

**structure.h**

```
typedef struct list{ //adding list here means you can use both list and struct list
    //...
}list;
```

**data_structure.h**

```
#include "structure.h"
```

And remove `#include "tokenizer.h"` as well as the structure declaration.

**tokenizer.h**

```
#include "structure.h"
```

And remove `#include "data_structure.h"`.